# How to set mysql date minimum and maximum value?

Tags: mysql, date, max, min, create-table

Is it possible to set minimum and maximum values in `MySQL` table definition?

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl` (
    `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `born` DATE MIN('1900-01-01') MAX('1999-12-31')
);
```

Comment: Typo: `UNSIGNET` should be `UNSIGNED`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you can use triggers to enforce date range:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl` (
    `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `born` DATE
);                 

CREATE TRIGGER `tbl_trg_ins` BEFORE INSERT ON  `tbl`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.`born` < '1900-01-01' OR NEW.`born` > '1999-12-31') THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '10000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'check constraint on tbb failed during insert';
    END IF;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER `tbl_trg_upd` BEFORE UPDATE ON  `tbl`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.`born` < '1900-01-01' OR NEW.`born` > '1999-12-31') THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '10000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'check constraint on tbl failed during update';
    END IF;
END;

INSERT INTO `tbl`
VALUES (1, '1990-12-12');

-- INSERT INTO `tbl`
-- VALUES (2, '2001-12-12');
-- 'check constraint on tbb failed during insert'
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36fdd/1/0)**</kbd>

When user tries to update/insert value that is not between `1900-01-01` and `1999-12-31`, he will get error.

Comment: @netdjw Can you elaborate? I hope that  typos don't change sense of answer.